# Convert UIViews made programmatically to UIScrollViews

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

So I have a bunch of `UIViews` that I made programmatically and placed a bunch of content on (`UIButtons`, `UILabels`, `UINavigationBars`, etc.), and most of these views are going to need to actually be `UIScrollViews` instead.

Now keep in mind I made all these through code not the Interface Builder. What I first tried was to just change each declaration of a `UIView` to a `UIScrollView` instead, and that compiled and ran fine, however, they were not scrollable. It's REALLY weird.

Here is the code that I change into `UIScrollViews`, although it doesn't scroll:

```
- (void)loadView {

     //allocate the view
     self.view = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
     //self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

     //set the view's background color
     self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MainBG.jpg"]];

     [self.view addSubview:[SiteOneController myNavBar1:@"Sites"]];

     NSMutableArray *sites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

     NSString *one = @"Constution Center";
     NSString *two = @"Franklin Court";
     NSString *three = @"Presidents House";

     [sites addObject: one];
     [one release];

     [sites addObject: two];
     [two release];

     [sites addObject: three];
     [three release];

     NSString *element;
     int j = 0;
     for (element in sites)
     {
         UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
         UIFont *myBoldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
         UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, b + (j*45), c, d)];
         [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

         label.text = element;
         label.font = myBoldFont;

         UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonBase.png"];
         [button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

         //setframe (where on screen)
         //separation is 15px past the width (45-30)
         button.frame = CGRectMake(a, b + (j*45), c, d);

         // [button setTitle:element forState:UIControlStateNormal];

         button.backgroundColor = [SiteOneController myColor1];

        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(showCCView:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [button setTag:j];

         [self.view addSubview: button];
         [self.view addSubview:label];
         j++;

     }

 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting a content size for the UIScrollView.

ie. `scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,760);`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. I'll make a note of that.

Comment: One more question though. I probably made a mistake in my original question. This transforms the entire UIView to a UIScrollView. Which means now, when I scroll through even the nav bar scrolls with it...How do you make just the UIScrollView only take up the space above the tab bar but below the nav bar.

Comment: Assuming that `SiteOneController` is a UINavigationBarController you may want to change your code so that you add the UIScrollView inside the SiteOneController, that should fix your problem.

Comment: SiteOneController is actually a UIViewController. I'm assuming if I add it inside this it will cover the nav bar at the top, but since the app is delegated by a TabBarController it would leave the tab bar untouched.

Comment: Well, your View with the NavigationBar is a child of the UITabBar, which is fine, so as long as the UIScrollView is a child of the ViewController with the NavBar, everything should work fine.

UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UIScrollView.  I have a similar setup in one of my apps, but I hide the TabBar Controller when the scroll view is present because I don't want the user to change tabs until they are done with the scroll view.